# List Opportunities that have a previous StageName [Advanced SOQL]

Tags: soql, fields, opportunity-history

I'm trying to get a list of Opportunities that have **now** "*Cancelled*" (isClosed=true and isWon=false) stageName  and the **previous** (Penultimate) value was "*Active*" by **SOQL** .

For example, the Opp X had these history

1. Created Active
2. Updated Active
3. Updated Paused
4. Updated Active
5. Updated Cancelled

This record should be return by the soql,  but it  shoudn't be returned if the step 4 doesn't exists.

In addition those opps should be and specific RecordType XX.

So far I've tried this:

```
Opportunity[] o =[select id from opportunity where isclosed = true and isWon = false  recordtype.name = 'XX'];
OpportunityHistory[] oh = [SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityHistory WHERE StageName = 'Active' and OpportunityId in:o ];
```

But I cant figure out **how to know that the second query is getting only the last previous Stage**

### Challenges

1. I have more than 10k Opps that should match

Comment: Does this have to be done in SOQL? What are you planning on doing with the records afterwards?

Comment: That was the initial idea in order use it in a batch as a base query. But now it could be apex as well

Answer (score 2):

The `OpportunityHistory` does hold a record for each change of an opportunity. So if it went to stage *Active*, there will be a record for that. So it should be possible to execute the following query:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Opportunity
WHERE IsClosed = true
AND IsWon = false
AND RecordType.name = 'XX'
AND Id IN (
    SELECT OpportunityId
    FROM OpportunityHistory
    WHERE StageName = 'Active'
)
```

It selects all Opportunities, which are not won and closed from a certain record type, if there is a history entry indicating that the Opoortunity has been *Active* once.

It is still debatable, if it will perform adequately with thousands of Opportunities and millions of OpportunityHistory entries. I would give it a try, since the query can be performed from the Developer Console without much effort.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this won work since I'm searching opps where only the penultimate status was 'Active'.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry - penultimate - nice word!

Comment: I must have overlooked the requrement with the funky name. I don't think that this can be solved in a single query. But you might try to query the `OpportunityHistory` for all closed/lost opportunities and order them by OpportunityId and CreatedDate. Then it is possible to iterate the list and inspect the last two history entries for each Opportunity.